# Render a form inside a modal - django

Tags: javascript, django, forms, django-urls

Probably my question is easy enough for people more experienced than me, so i would like your help with the following. I would like to use a modal on my website for Login/Register and i have an issue when rendering a form inside the modal.

I've created a urls.py file

```
app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='register')
]
```

the views.py file where loading the AccountRegisterForm

```
class UserRegisterView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'users/register.html'
    form_class = AccountRegisterForm
    success_url = '/'
    success_message = "Your account has been created!"
```

the template

```
<li class="list-inline-item list_s"><a href="#" class="btn flaticon-user" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg"> <span class="dn-lg">Login/Register</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="sign_up_modal modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body container pb20">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <ul class="sign_up_tab nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Login</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Register</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and the form:

```
<form method="POST" form action="{% url 'users:register' %}">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook float-left mt5"></i> Login with Facebook</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-googl"><i class="fa fa-google float-left mt5"></i> Login with Google</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <hr>
                                        {{form.as_p}}
                                        <div class="form-group custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="exampleCheck2">
                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="exampleCheck2">I have read and accept the Terms and Privacy Policy?</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-log btn-block btn-thm">Sign Up</button>
                                        <p class="text-center">Already have an account? <a class="text-thm" href="#">Log In</a></p>
                                    </form>
```

Now, the modal can be opened from http://localhost:7000 where user can click on Login/Register button. However i've created a new url http://localhost:7000/users/register where again modal can be opened by clicking Login/Register and i render the form successfully.
The question is how i can render the form in the home page and not in the /users/register?
Thank you!

Comment: How is your home page rendered?  What kind of view are you using?  TemplateView, or some other view with context?  In other words, is the content static?

Comment: I'm using (TemplateView) like class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/index.html'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the form in a TemplateView, you don't have access to the form variables, so you would have to manually code it in your HTML.  Go to your /users/register page and view source, copy the form and paste it into your home page modal.